# Cocossharp Sprite Masking

Tags: xamarin, cocossharp

I'm working on building a slot machine reel. My idea is to stack all the images and move them downward and then back to the top once it gets out of view.
In order for this to work, I would have to mask the areas outside of the area I want displayed.

Each reel has 27 different images on it. 
I tried CCMaskedSprite but can't figure out how it works.

**Update**

Given the image below, I want to mask, or hide all the graphics outside the viewable area.

[image]

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you need ? Or show us some code you've done so far ?

Comment: I added an image